# Unity, when humanoids add Rigidbody, It bounces on the floor, slips and changes position

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a humanoid in Unity.
But when humanoids add Rigidbody,
It bounces on the floor, slips and changes position.

What could be a problem?

I added a humanoid in the Asset Store.
'Apply Root Motion' is not checked.

However, humanoids are vibrating and sliding.

Hope the humanoid stays still on the floor.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.